# How to disable/circumvent "Large pull requests can only be viewed by loading files individually." in a new BitBucket PR overhaul?

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

> This is a large pull request. Large pull requests can only be viewed by loading files individually.

I don't care if it takes a minute to load, but I would strongly prefer to see **all** changes at  once instead of having to use clumsy substitutes like navigating in a file tree or using next/previous buttons.

For a previous version of the PR screen of BitBucket one could use Refined BitBucket addon, but sadly it seems that for the new "improved" PR screen this feature is no longer supported.